# Closure with parameter inside array

Tags: php, php-5.4

I have problem with closure in PHP 5.4

I have array

```
public function check(){
return ['int'=>['filter'=>2],
'min'=>function($val){
return ['int'=>2,'min'=>$val];
}
]
}
```

When I use

```
(new Obj())->check()['int'];
```

it works. But I don't know how use min with parameter for example 3

I tryed

```
(new Obj())->check()['min'](3);
(new Obj())->check()['min'(3)];
(new Obj())->check()['min(3)'];
```

don't work.

Comment: The most valid way is `(new Obj())->check()['min'](3);` - what is your result ? Any error ?

Comment: @hsz: That would be valid and correct in a language with a formal grammar. PHP is not that language.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('
Buy in real enviroment I use 
`(new Valid())->checkVal()['min'](3);`

Comment: @110precent Even error message says that this is wrong syntax for php. Also, I hope you don't use stuff like this in real-world projects. 1. This really hurts eyes (and might hurt brain). 2. Syntax may change from version to version and the first thing that may become invalid is this kind of structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's parser is simply not up to the task, so you can't write this expression as you could have in other languages. You will have to use a workaround, for example:

```
call_user_func((new Obj())->check()['min'], 3));
```

Or alternatively:

```
$f = (new Obj())->check()['min'];
$f(3);
```

Comment: What about `((new Obj())->check()['min'])(3)` ?

Comment: @hsz still invalid syntax.